# How to detect the python package name inside the script

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-3.7

I am trying to install pip libraries inside a python script so I would issue the command:

```
os.system('python -m pip install requests > null 2>&1')
```

However this script will be run by different users on different hosts and on some hosts, `python` package is installed as `python2` or `python3` (same for `pip`) rather that just `python`. This makes the command above not work since it doesn't detect the name `python`.

So is there any way to detect the `python` package name on the client hosts so the installation can work?

(I know that it's better to use the `subprocess` library to install pip packages but I am using `os.system` for a specific reason).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sys.executable` to get full path to `python`:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'/home/***/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/bin/python3.8'
```

Then use that path to run `python`

```
os.system('{} -m pip install requests > null 2>&1'.format(sys.executable))
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Do you know how to check for windows hosts?

Comment: Doesn't this work for windows? It should work, I believe.